# python code does not show data in mysql database

Tags: python, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, raspberry-pi

I have created a touch screen buttons consist of "start" "Request material" "Receive material" "Lap" "Emergency" "Finish"
Now i am trying to store integers as numbers of finished products (1,2,3,etc) and lap times when an operator presses the lap button (similar to stopwatch). Basically, there are only two columns. The result shows in the terminal after i ran the program and there was no error, but it didn't show in the mysql database and i am using phpmyadmin. Here is my code can be seen below:

```
from Tkinter import *
from pymodbus.client.sync import ModbusTcpClient as ModbusClient
import time
import datetime
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import MySQLdb


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(0)
#-------------------------------------------------------GPIO
GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.OUT)#red led
GPIO.setup(20, GPIO.OUT)#yellow led
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.OUT)#green led

GPIO.output(21, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(20, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(16, GPIO.HIGH)
#-------------------------------------------------------GPIO

class Screen(Frame):
  def __init__(self, master):
      Frame.__init__(self, master)
#-------------------------------------------------------Main
      self.lbttn_clicks = 0
      self.start_button()
      self.material_button()
      self.receive_button()
      self.emergency_button()
      self.lap_button()
      self.finish_button()
      self.minutes = 0
      self.seconds = 0
#-------------------------------------------------------Modbus Var
      self.LedRed_State = False
      self.LedYellow_State = False
      self.LedGreen_State = False
      self.db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","raspberry","DB_ASSY")
      self.sql = "INSERT INTO Table_Assembly (Finished Product, Lap Time) VALUES (%s, %s)"
      self.c= self.db.cursor()
      self.client = ModbusClient('192.168.4.166')
      self.client.connect()
      print "ModbusClient connected..."
#-------------------------------------------------------Modbus Var

      self.time_start = time.time()
      self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
#-------------------------------------------------------Main

#-------------------------------------------------------Stopwatch
      self._start = 0.0
      self._elapsedtime = 0.0
      self._running = 0
      self.timestr = StringVar()
      # self.makeWidgets()
#-------------------------------------------------------Stopwatch

#--------------------------------------------------------------------Main funcs
 def start_button(self):
     self.gbttn = Button(self)
     self.gbttn['text'] = "Start"
     self.gbttn['command'] = lambda: [ f() for f in  [self.Start, 
self.LedGreen, self.LedYellowOff, self.LedRedOff]]
    self.gbttn.place(x = 100, y = 0)

 def material_button(self):
     self.ybttn = Button(self)
     self.ybttn['text'] = "Request Material"
     self.ybttn['command'] = self.LedYellow
     self.ybttn.place(x=100, y=50)

 def receive_button(self):
     self.rbttn = Button(self)
     self.rbttn ['text'] = "Receive Material"
     self.rbttn ['command'] = self.LedYellowOff
     self.rbttn.place(x=100, y=100)

 def emergency_button(self):
     self.ebttn = Button(self)
     self.ebttn['text'] = "Emergency"
     self.ebttn['command'] = lambda: [f() for f in [self.LedRed, self.LedYellowOff, self.LedGreenOff]]
     self.ebttn.place(x=100,y=150)

 def lap_button(self):
     self.lbttn = Button(self)
     self.lbttn['text'] = "Lap"
     self.lbttn['command'] = lambda: [ f() for f in  [self.lap_count, self.Start, self.insert_to_db]]
     self.lbttn.place(x=100,y=200)

 def finish_button(self):
     self.fbttn = Button(self)
     self.fbttn['text'] = "Finish"
     self.fbttn['command'] = lambda: [f() for f in [self.Finish, self.Stop, self.Reset]]
     self.fbttn.place(x=100, y=250)

 def lap_count(self):
     self.lbttn_clicks += 1
     print str(self.lbttn_clicks)

 # def stop_watch(self):
 #     print self.seconds
 #     time.sleep(1)
 #     self.seconds = int(time.time() - self.time_start)
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Main funcs

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Modbus funcs

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Modbus funcs

#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Stopwatch funcs
 # def makeWidgets(self):
 #     """ Print the time. """
 #     l = Label(self, textvariable=self.timestr)
 #     self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
 #     l.pack(fill=X, expand=NO, pady=2, padx=2)
 def _print(self):
     print self._elapsedtime

 def _update(self):
     """ Update the label with elapsed time. """
     self._elapsedtime = time.time() - self._start
     self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
     self._timer = self.after(50, self._update)

 def _setTime(self, elap):
     """ Set the time string to Minutes:Seconds:Hundreths """
     minutes = int(elap / 60)
     seconds = int(elap - minutes * 60.0)
     hseconds = int((elap - minutes * 60.0 - seconds) * 100)
     self.timestr.set('%02d:%02d:%02d' % (minutes, seconds, hseconds))

 def Start(self):
     """ Start the stopwatch, ignore if running. """
     print self._elapsedtime
     if not self._running:
         self._start = time.time() - self._elapsedtime
         self._update()
         self._running = 1

 def insert_to_db(self):
     self.sql = "INSERT INTO Table_Assembly ('Finished_Product', 'Lap_Time') VALUES (%s, %s)"
     try:
         self.execute(sql,( str(self.lbttn_clicks), str(self._elapsedtime)))
         self.db.commit()
     except:
         self.db.rollback()

 def read_from_db(self):
     try:
         #c.execute("SELECT * FROM TTAB_CPU WHERE ID = (SELCET MAX(ID) FROM TAB_CPU)")
         self.c.execute("SELECT * FROM Table_Assembly ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1")      
         self.result = self.c.fetchall()
         if result is not None:
              print ('Finished_Product: ' , result[0][1], '| Lap_Time: ' , result[0][2])
     except:
         print ("read error")



 def LedGreen(self):
     self.rr = self.client.read_coils(0,6)
     print "Start Button Pressed"
     if self.LedGreen_State == False:
        self.rr.bits[3] = True
        self.rq = self.client.write_coil(3, True)
        self.rq = self.client.write_coil(0, True)
        GPIO.output(16, GPIO.LOW)
        self.LedGreen_State = True

 def LedGreenOff(self):
     self.rr = self.client.read_coils(0,6)
     print "Green light is off"
     if self.LedGreen_State == True:
        self.rr.bits[3] = False
        self.rq = self.client.write_coil(3, False)
        self.rq = self.client.write_coil(0, False)
        GPIO.output(16, GPIO.HIGH)
        self.LedGreen_State = False

 def LedYellow(self):
     self.rr = self.client.read_coils(0,6)
     print "Request Material"
     if self.LedYellow_State == False:
        self.rr.bits[4] = True
        self.rq = self.client.write_coil(4, True)
        self.rq = self.client.write_coil(1, True)
        GPIO.output(20, GPIO.LOW)
        self.LedYellow_State = True

 def LedYellowOff(self):
     self.rr = self.client.read_coils(0,6)
     print "Material replenished"
     if self.LedYellow_State == True:
        self.rr.bits[4] = False
        self.rq = self.client.write_coil(4, False)
        self.rq = self.client.write_coil(1, False)
        GPIO.output(20, GPIO.HIGH)
        self.LedYellow_State = False

 def LedRed(self):
     self.rr = self.client.read_coils(0,6)
     print "Assembly process jammed"
     if self.LedRed_State == False:
        self.rr.bits[5] = True
        self.rq = self.client.write_coil(5, True)
        self.rq = self.client.write_coil(2, True)
        GPIO.output(21, GPIO.LOW)
        self.LedRed_State = True

 def LedRedOff(self):
     self.rr = self.client.read_coils(0,6)
     print "Red light is off"
     if self.LedRed_State == True:
        self.rr.bits[5] = False
        self.rq = self.client.write_coil(5, False)
        self.rq = self.client.write_coil(2, False)
        GPIO.output(21, GPIO.HIGH)
        self.LedRed_State = False

 def Finish(self):
     self.rr = self.client.read_coils(0,6)
     print "Assembly is finished"
     if self.LedGreen_State == True:
        self.rr.bits[3] = False
        self.rq = self.client.write_coil(3, False)
        self.rq = self.client.write_coil(0, False)
        GPIO.output(16, GPIO.HIGH)
        self.LedGreen_State = False

    if self.LedYellow_State == True:
        self.rr.bits[4] = False
        self.rq = self.client.write_coil(4, False)
        self.rq = self.client.write_coil(1, False)
        GPIO.output(20, GPIO.HIGH)
        self.LedYellow_State = False

    if self.LedRed_State == True:
        self.rr.bits[5] = False
        self.rq = self.client.write_coil(5, False)
        self.rq = self.client.write_coil(2, False)
        GPIO.output(21, GPIO.HIGH)
        self.LedRed_State = False   


 def Stop(self):
     """ Stop the stopwatch, ignore if stopped. """
     if self._running:
        self.after_cancel(self._timer)
        self._elapsedtime = time.time() - self._start
        self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)
        self._running = 0
        GPIO.cleanup()

 def Reset(self):
     """ Reset the stopwatch. """
     self._start = time.time()
     self._elapsedtime = 0.0
     self._setTime(self._elapsedtime)

 def main():
     while 1:
         insert_to_db()
         read_from_db()

 if __name__ == '__main__':
     try:
         db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","raspberry","DB_ASSY")
         self.c= self.db.cursor()

     except:
         print ("No connection to server...")
win = Tk()
win.title("Screen")
win.geometry('800x400')
app = Screen(win)

win.mainloop()
```

Please share 
Thank you
and by the way i am using raspberry pi with raspbian stretch

Answer (score 0):

Every transnational(Insert, update and delete) query required to commit than after reflect db engine. So try with autocommit(True) or commit manual after query execution.

```
 self.db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","raspberry","DB_ASSY")
 self.sql = "INSERT INTO Table_Assembly (Finished Product, Lap Time) VALUES (%s, %s)"
 self.c= self.db.cursor()
 self.db.commit()
```

Comment: Another point don't give fields name with space use underscore.
`Finished product ` should be `finished_product` or `FinishedProduct`

Comment: well I tried what you told me yesterday and it didn't work either. I've tried several things and the results were the same. I think there is some changes to be made at def insert_to_db(self) section but i am kinda stuck for now. I really need help with this thank you